# Generic base class to handle CRUD operations

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, crud

I have a business requirement to consolidate CRUD operations into a single base class, regardless of the type of object.  I am not able to modify the calling code, which could be anything ... so if there are a bunch of callers that look like this:

```
var state = new State("New York");
state.Save();

var city = new City("New York", state);
city.Save();

var stadium = new Stadium("Yankee Stadium", city);
stadium.Save();
```

All of these `Save` methods would need to be handle in one, single common base class.

The path I've lead myself down is to create a single generic abstract base class which these classes implement, such as the following ...

```
public abstract class PersistableObject<T> where T : class {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public static T Find(string id) {}
    public void Save() { }
    public void Delete() { } 
}
```

I then have the above objects inherit from this class:

```
public class City: PersistableObject<City> { }
```

I stripped out the CRUD methods tied to the concrete implementations and after having these various objects inherit from the abstract base class, the solution compiles without error.

And now I'm stuck.  The backing store is a *local XML document* (decision out of my hands).  I am guessing I can serialize these to XML using the normal XML serializers in .Net, but is there a better way to do this?  Should I be using some sort of a repository pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: Same question you asked yesterday?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I removed it after I thought I'd come up with a better solution but am back to the same place, so throwing it out there again.  I tried to go with a full repository pattern and it became overly complex and seemed I was headed down the wrong path.  The above is clean and the entire thing compiles without issue, but I'm missing the serialization step of the generics in the base class (as well as the concept of if these is even a sound approach).

Comment: You shouldn't add new question, you should have undeleted the previous one.

Comment: @DavidG My mistake, I honestly didn't realize that was an option ... I did look at my recently asked list to see if it was there to do exactly that.  I must have missed it.  Will in the future.